# Is there a way to have multiple callback in DuplexChannelFactory<>?

Tags: c#, wcf, ipc

I already know how to create a WCF duplex channel from my desktop application to a service with callback. I augmented the service interface and created two callback interfaces. I also want to connect my system tray applet to the service.

Is there a way to have both callbacks?

The app would not care about the tray callback, just its own, while the tray applet would only care about the tray, not the application.

Since both applications register the callback, one overlaps the other, as stored in a static variable on the service end. That causes grief, not to mention inappropriate methods.

```
// In the tray
//
var callbackTray = new IpcAppToServiceBackTray();
InstanceContext callbackInstanceTray = new InstanceContext(callbackTray);

var callbackApp = new IpcAppToServiceBackApp();
InstanceContext callbackInstanceApp = new InstanceContext(callbackApp);

NetNamedPipeBinding ipcBinding = new NetNamedPipeBinding()
{
    Security = new NetNamedPipeSecurity() { Mode = NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None },
};

EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/ResqIpcAppToService");

ComAppToService.IpcFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IIpcAppToService>(callbackInstanceTray, ipcBinding, endpointAddress);

Program.HostIpcAppToService = ComAppToService.IpcFactory.CreateChannel();
Program.HostIpcAppToService.OpenCallbackTray();
...


// In the service
//
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
public class IpcAppToService : IIpcAppToService, IErrorHandler
{
    public static IIpcAppToServiceBackApp CallbackApp { get; private set; } = null;

    public void OpenCallbackApp()
    {
        IpcAppToService.CallbackApp = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IIpcAppToServiceBackApp>();
    }

    public static IIpcAppToServiceBackTray CallbackTray { get; private set; } = null;

    public void OpenCallbackTray()
    {
        IpcAppToService.CallbackTray = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IIpcAppToServiceBackTray>();
    }

    ...
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I believe that I have a solution, just have to try it out. I just have to pass an enum in the OpenCallback() method. If so, I will delete this question. I would just use one interface, which I would personalize. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is a partial solution. Adding an enum to OpenCallback solved one problem.

```
// Interface Definition
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
[FaultContractAttribute(typeof(IpcToTrayFault))]
void OpenCallback(IpcCallbackDest callbackDest);

// In Service
//
public static IIpcAppToServiceBack CallbackApp { get; private set; } = null;
public static IIpcAppToServiceBack CallbackTray { get; private set; } = null;

public void OpenCallback(IpcCallbackDest callbackDest)
{
    switch (callbackDest)
    {
        case IpcCallbackDest.App:
            IpcAppToService.CallbackApp = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IIpcAppToServiceBack>();
            break;
        case IpcCallbackDest.Tray:
            IpcAppToService.CallbackTray = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IIpcAppToServiceBack>();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

If the service uses a callback that is not registered, then storing that in a queue for later processing, solves the other.

I had to merge both callback objects back together. I was hoping to keep them separate. There must be an interface definition, so base and derived classes do not work.

At least, my static callbacks do not get clobbered.